# Iterating over the array returned from a function in another service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, iteration

I have a function in my controller that is making a call to a function defined in a service shared by that controller. I am able to make a call correctly, but the function returns an array and i want to get individual item from that array. Here is the snippet

```
    ctrl.loadInterfaces = function(driver) {
      angular.forEach(ctrl.driverInterfaces, function(value, key){
        ctrl.interfaces = myservice.driverInfo(driver, value);
      })
    };
```

So here, driverInfo() will return an array, something like ['one', 'two'] but now i want to split that and put individually 'one' and 'two' into ctrl.interfaces and not like an array. Any idea how should i do that?
By the way ctrl.driverInterfaces is just another static array declared in the controller.

My html

```
    <select>
      <option ng-repeat="interface in ctrl.interfaces" 
              value="{$ interface }">{$ interface $}</option>
      </select>
```

Inputs are much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What kind of data structure is `ctrl.interfaces`? Is it an array?

Comment: Hi CodeWarrior, i have defined that as ctrl.interfaces = null for now.

Comment: so just an object for now

Comment: You wanted to iterate over the array returned by `myservice.driverInfo()`. How did you want to populate the `ctrl.interfaces`. Do you have a pattern like, the first element should go to `ctrl.interfaces.name`, second element to `ctrl.interfaces.id`, etc?

Comment: I can change ctrl.interfaces = [], if that would make things easy for what i want to achieve.

Comment: Actually I would just like it to be an array which i can show in the drop down

Comment: I will change the code to declare it as an array, like this ctrl.interfaces = []

Comment: Ok, then you just need to create a copy of the array and not use the original array returned by `myservice.driverInfo()`, correct?

Comment: Yes, i have this in my html

Comment: Edited the post with my html. If you see i am reading ctrl.interfaces in ng-repeat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146206/discussion-between-codewarrior-and-user3339691).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ctrl.loadInterfaces = function(driver) {
  ctrl.interfaces = [];
  angular.forEach(ctrl.driverInterfaces, function(value, key){
    ctrl.interfaces = ctrl.interfaces.concat(myservice.driverInfo(driver, value));
  })
};
```

Comment: Will i able to use ctrl.interfaces in ng-repeat like interface in ctrl.interfaces then? And use the value in <option>{$ interface $}</option>?

Comment: What are the properties within `interface`? I'm just trying to find out the attribute within it that you'd like to be the display text and which property you'd like to be the value.

Comment: You can use something like this. You can replace `.value` and `.description` with the proper attribute names `<select> <option ng-repeat="interface in ctrl.interfaces" value="{{interface.value}}">{{interface.description}}</option> </select>`

Comment: Can we open a chat, will explain my thing there?

Comment: Hey don't see you in chat? Could you paste the link please

Comment: So, this code is actually giving me as many number of items there are in ctrl.driverInterfaces (which is a static array declared in the controller). So basically my drop down is showing like Item1{'x', 'y'} Item2{'x', 'y'}

Comment: Can you log the output of `myservice.driverInfo(driver, value)` to the console and let us know how it looks like. I'm thinking it is not in an array format.

Comment: Thanks CodeWarrior for your great inputs. I was able to solve that problem with nested angular.forEach

Comment: appreciate your help :)